# How to reformulate an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

i am not an expert in sql programming and i was wondering if you can help me reformulate the following query using INNER JOIN?

```
db_query("
    select max(field_date_and_time_value2) as last_time 
    from field_data_field_date_and_time 
    where (field_date_and_time_value2 > '".$today."') 
    AND (".$node->uid." = (select uid from node where nid = " . $node->nid ."))");
```

Comment: What is the name of your `uid` field in your  `field_data_field_date_and_time ` table?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT
    max(a.field_date_and_time_value2) as last_time
    , b.uid
FROM field_data_field_date_and_time a
    INNER JOIN
        node b
    ON
        /* this piece might be wrong. what is the relationship between the first table and the second one? */
        b.nid = '".$node->nid."'
where
    a.field_date_and_time_value2 > '".$today."' AND
    b.uid = $node->nid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `field_date_and_time` table has a column called `uid` having the same meaning as that column in your `node` table, here's what you need to do.

```
      SELECT MAX(A.field_date_and_time_value2) AS last_time
        FROM field_date_and_time A
  INNER JOIN node B ON A.uid = B.uid
       WHERE B.nid = '".$node->nid."'
         AND A.field_date_and_time_value2 > '".$today."'
```

Beware SQL injection attacks! Avoid substituting variables directly into SQL statements unless you're really sure those variables can't be corrupted by badguy users! Remember the story of the guy named

```
"johnny ; drop tables *;"
```

Comment: I believe Little Bobby Table's full first name was "`Robert'; DROP TABLE students; --`"